# Regex to extract calls to a function in javascript text

Tags: java, regex

I'm building an app that scrapes, from an html webpage,
the way that the page displays errors in javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    toastr.error('ERROR1');
    toastr.error('ERROR2');
...
</script>
```

I need to build a regex that extract ERROR1 and ERROR2 etc.. one by one

Comment: you mean the result of `toastr.error('ERROR1');` and `toastr.error('ERROR1');` or just the `ERROR1` and `ERROR1` String?

Comment: What have you tried?  Also, we can help you better if you provide a [mcve] of your attempt; it helps us understand better exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to get only the exact `ERROR1` and `ERROR2` this mean you should to get every thing between `toastr.error('` and `');` so this can help you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"
            + "toastr.error('ERROR1');"
            + "toastr.error('ERROR2');"
            + "..."
            + "</script>";
    String regexString = Pattern.quote("toastr.error('") + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote("');");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

This will return a result like this :

```
ERROR1
ERROR2
```

Comment: It should be noted that this will not properly capture an error message like: `toastr.error('ERROR3: value='+variable);` ... since the call to `toastr.error(...)` does not end exactly with the characters `');`.  RegEx matching is fragile.

Comment: mmm i think you are right @AJNeufeld i only answered of what he said in his question, but do think i should to make it better like you said in comment :) ?

Comment: No, your answer is fine (I upvoted it, even).  The OP did not express whether they wanted `ERROR1` or `'ERROR1'`, or `toastr.error('ERROR1');` returned.  If you try to capture only what is in the `(...)`'s, it will break on error messages containing the `)` character.  The OP asked for a RegEx; a general answer would require an actual parser, which is way beyond the question.  My comment/warning was for the OP, when they use your code.